# VideoEvent not working in Flash Player 10.2

Tags: actionscript-3

VideoEvent doesnot work in flash player 10.2

```
import fl.video.VideoEvent 

addEventListener(VideoEvent.READY, ready);


Compiler Error: ( For Flash Player 10.2, works fine in Flash Player 9)
1119: Access of possibly undefined property READY through a reference with static type Class.
```

Any suggestions on solving this ?

Comment: Anyways.. got this working. Seems like compiler confuses with flash.events.VideoEvent

So just adding the full reference solved the problem :
addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.READY, ready);

Comment: Thank you for posting the question and the answer. Very helpful for me. I was going nuts after having to change an old project from player 9 to 10, due to an incompatibility with Vimeo API (not directly related to this issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(As this was solved a while back, I'm posting the answer here as a public courtesy to get this off the unanswered list. Asker is welcome to post their own answer and accept it, or just accept this one. Whichever.)

The compiler apparently gets confused with fl.video.VideoEvent. Use the full reference instead.

`addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.READY, ready);`